# Karma + Webpack Angular controller not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, webpack

I've set up an Angular project using webpack [with help from this blog post](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/) which has [an associated boilerplate on Github](https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack).

The app itself is working fine, but when I run karma it says it can't find the controller it is trying to test.

```
// karma.config.js
module.exports = config => config.set({
  files: ['test.webpack.js'],
  preprocessors: {
    'test.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
  },
  browsers: ['PhantomJS2'],
  webpack: require('./webpack.config'),
  webpackMiddleware: {
    noInfo: 'errors-only',
  },
});

// test.webpack.js
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks/angular-mocks';

const testContext = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.js$/);
testContext.keys().forEach(testContext);
```

I only have one spec file right now for `MainCtrl.spec.js`. Karma will run it, but I get the error:

> Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

When I actually run the app, `MainCtrl` seems to load just fine, so I'm not sure why Karma can't get it.

I've also tried changing `\.spec\.js` to just `\.js` but this causes way more errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by rethinking the workflow a bit. Two main issues are that `module` does not get globally exported from `ngMocks` (there is a conflict with the node import system). The other is that the tests also have to load all of the module files first which is pretty typical for Karma.

```
// karma.config.js
files: ['app/index.js', 'test.webpack.js']
preprocessors: {
  'app/index.js': ['webpack'],
  'test.webpack.js': ['webpack'],
}


// test.config.js
/* Angular is already imported by app/index.js */
import 'angular-mocks/angular-mocks';

/* MUST use `angular.mock.module`. `module` alone won't work */    
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ngculator'));
const testContext = require.context('.', true, /\.spec\.js$/);
testContext.keys().forEach(testContext);
```